# the 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /target/

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, system-installation, grub2, error-handling

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 but I get this error at the end of installation process!

I tried to create a partition with `ext4` for `\boot`. also `ext1` but non of them worked. Also I tried to choose the `ntfs` partition that my Windows 10 grub file is in that but didn't work too.

I also had Ubuntu 16.04 beside my Windows 10 on this Laptop, But when I tried to format the old Linux and install the new one, I get this error message!

(My Windows is installed on sda (Samsung ssd hard))

Edit: Screen shot didn't work and couldn't large the window to show off all the partitions, so I took 2 images:

[image]
[image]